# Functorial descripiton of Low Degree Cohomology of Eilenberg-MacLane spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, eilenberg-maclane-spaces

I remember stumbling across a paper in which the author(s) compute the cohomology groups $$H^{n+k}(K(a,n);\mathbb{Z})$$ of the Eilenberg-MacLane space $K(a,n)$ on the finite abelian group $A$, for low but interesting $k,n$. In particular, they give a functorial description in of these groups in $A$.

Does anyone know which paper I am refering to???

Comment: Random guess:  This one:  https://www.jstor.org/stable/1969820?seq=14  ?  Part 2 https://www.jstor.org/stable/1969702?seq=73 has some computations, e.g., $n=3$ is covered in Section 23.

Comment: Fair guess! If I remember correctly the paper I'm refering to is quite a bit more recent and also talks about the n=4 case!